# htaccess redirect from non-www to www but not when subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I made this code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This successfully forwards me from //hallo.com to //www.hallo.com

But it also forwards me from //language.hallo.com to //www.language.hallo.com what shall not happen. How can I prevent the latter problem and only do this rule for non-www to www without subdomain impact?

Answer (score 0):

Your rule needs a RewriteCond to exclude the subdomain

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^sub.domain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Huh? Could you be more specific?

Comment: all Images and CSS resources are not loaded anymore then!"